# What is the default color of ?attr/colorControlHighlight in android?

Tags: android, colors

I need to know the default color of ?attr/colorControlHighlight in android because I need to apply the same color for my buttons press state background in my drawable for pre lollipop devices. ?attr/colorControlHighlight is one of the attributes from lollipop that you can't use on pre lollipop or else it would trigger an error.

Comment: ctrl + click on it it will take you to its value

Comment: @NarendraKothamire thank you very much!!!!!!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`?attr/colorControlHighlight` is a reference to a `colorControlHighlight` value defined in attr xml.

**attrs.xml** is a file located in:

> android_sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res\values\attrs.xml

Here, all of the attributes, that you may use in your app, are located.

If we check that file, we will find

`<attr name="colorControlHighlight" format="color" />` string,

which means that `colorControlHighlight` itself is a reference to a color.

And all attributes declared here are just references to another values.
The actual values are assigned in **themes.xml** file, which, in it's turn, is located in:

> android-sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res\values\themes.xml

If we check that file, we'll find, that there are a lot of themes, which are using our `colorControlHighlight` reference. So whether you are using one theme or another in your application, the `colorControlHighlight` values would be different for each of them.

In our case there are 2 themes:

`<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/legacy_button_pressed</item>`
for Theme

and

`<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/legacy_light_button_pressed</item>` for Theme.Light

Here we see another references instead of values. But now they refer to the color attribute: `@color/`. Thus we need to move to the **color.xml** files.

These are

> android-sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res\values\colors.xml
>
> android-sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res\values\colors_holo.xml
>
> android-sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res\values\colors_leanback.xml
>
> android-sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res\values\colors_legacy.xml
>
> android-sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res\values\colors_material.xml

Simple file check brings out the actual values we were looking for:

in the **colors-legacy.xml** file:

`<color name="legacy_button_pressed">#fffea50b</color>`

and

`<color name="legacy_light_button_pressed">@color/legacy_button_pressed</color>`
which also refers to the first color.

So, the color we searched for, was **#fffea50b**